# License error attempting to implement AppHostHttpListenerBase

Tags: servicestack

I'm attempting to create a second App host for self-hosting, so my unit tests are in the same process as the service, to aid debugging.  I created the new app host as follows.  When my Unit test calls the .Init() method, I receive the following error:

ServiceStack.LicenseException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=The free-quota limit on '10 ServiceStack Operations' has been reached. Please see https://servicestack.net to upgrade to a commercial license or visit https://github.com/ServiceStackV3/ServiceStackV3 to revert back to the free ServiceStack v3.
  Source=ServiceStack.Text

The class below is in the same assembly as my real AppHost (my main ASP.NET service project)., so there is definitely a license key in the web.config. file.

```
    public class ServiceTestAppHost : AppSelfHostBase
    {
        public const string BaseUrl = "http://localhost/dvsvc";

        public ServiceTestAppHost()
            : base("Test Web Services", typeof(DV.Svc.Interface.HelloService).Assembly) { }

        public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
        {
            ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig.IncludeNullValues = true;
            ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig.DateHandler = ServiceStack.Text.DateHandler.ISO8601;
            ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig.ExcludeTypeInfo = true;   //exclude the type specification               
            ServiceStack.Formats.HtmlFormat.Humanize = false;

            //most apps use credentials auth.  the TVTI player uses Basic auth
            Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() =>
                new DVAuthUserSession(),
                new ServiceStack.Auth.IAuthProvider[] { new DVCredentialsAuthProvider(), new DVBasicAuthProvider() })
            /*{ HtmlRedirect = null }*/
            );

            //in memory cache
            container.RegisterAs<MemoryCacheClient, ICacheClient>();

            SetConfig(new HostConfig { DebugMode = true });

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Self hosted applications don't read from `Web.config`, they read from the app config `App.config`, so you would have to create an appropriate config file for the host executable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <add key="servicestack:license" value="{licenseKeyText}" />
</configuration>
```